# Importing nested list into a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on a problem which I realise I  am probably approaching the wrong way but am now confused and out of ideas. Any research that I have done has left me more confused, and thus I have come for help.

I have a nested list:

> [['# Name Surname', 'Age', 'Class', 'Score', '\n'], ['name', '9', 'B',
>   'N/A', '\n'], ['name1', '9', 'B', 'N/A', '\n'], ['name2', '8', 'B',
>   'N/A', '\n'], ['name3', '9', 'B', 'N/A', '\n'], ['name4', '8', 'B',
>   'N/A', '']]

I am trying to make it so this list is imported into a text file in the correct layout. For this I flattened the string and then joined it together with ','.

The problem with this is that because the '\n' is being stored in the list itself, it adds a comma after this, which ends up turning this:

> ## Name Surname,Age,Class,Score,
>
> Name,9,B,N/A,
>
> Name1,9,B,N/A,
>
> Name2,8,B,N/A,
>
> Name3,9,B,N/A,
>
> Name4,8,B,N/A,

into:

> ## Name Surname,Age,Class,Score,
>
> ,
>
> ,Name,9,B,N/A,
>
> ,Name1,9,B,N/A,
>
> ,Name2,8,B,N/A,
>
> ,Name3,9,B,N/A,
>
> ,Name4,8,B,N/A,

If I remove the \n from the code the formatting in the text file is all wrong due to no new lines.

Is there a better way to approach this or is there a quick fix to all my problems that I cannot see?

Thanks!

My code for reference:

```
def scorestore(score):

    user[accountLocation][3] = score


    file = ("classdata",schclass,".txt")
    file = "".join(file)

    flattened = [val for sublist in user for val in sublist]

    flatstring = ','.join(str(v) for v in flattened)



    accountlist = open(file,"w")

    accountlist.write(flatstring)

    accountlist.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which list is the one in your post (sublist?) but when you flatten it, just discard the "\n" strings:

```
flattened = [x for x in sublist if x != ["\n"]]
```

Comment: Sublist was just a variable name. What you've posted above just throws me with syntax errors since there isn't a python term I believe.

Comment: Replace sublist in my command with the name of the nested list you posted. Whatever the names are, looping through your nested list, and ignoring entries that are just naked new lines does exactly what you asked.

Comment: I fixed that part, try now

Comment: I think I tried this earlier and it said that x was not defined, let me have another look

Comment: X was defined, I obviously messed something up. But its still not inputting it back into the text file in the original format. I's a bit bizzare I know but for the task I believe the text file itself has to also be readable which is why I wanted to make it visible to see. This method just puts back the results as separate lists, rather than being able to keep them in the original form.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to remove the newlines from the sublists as you get them, the print each sublist one at a time. This would look something like:

```
for sublist in users:
    print(",".join(val for val in sublist if not val.isspace()), file=accountlist)
```

This will fail on the 0 in your list, however. I'm not sure if you intend to handle that, or if it's extraneous. If you do need to handle is, then you'll have to change the generator expression to `str(val) for val in sublist if not str(val).isspace()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making one string, how about writing lines. Use something like this:

```
 list_of_list = [[...]]
 lines = [','.join(line).strip() for line in list_of_list]
 lines = [line for line in lines if line]
 open(file,'w').writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Problem is that the nested list is being imported from the file, and this seems to want a string to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `csv` module to make it easier:

```
import csv

data = [
    ['# Name Surname', 'Age', 'Class', 'Score','\n'],
    ['\n'],
    ['Name', '9', 'B', 'N/A','\n'],
    ['Name1', '9', 'B', 'N/A','\n'],
    ['Name2', '8', 'B', 'N/A','\n'],
    ['Name3', '9', 'B', 'N/A','\n'],
    ['Name4', '8', 'B', 0]
]

# Remove all the ending new lines
data = [row[:-1] if row[-1] == '\n' else row for row in data]

# Write to file
with open('write_sublists.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

## Discussion

Your data is irregular: some row contains the ending new line, some row don't. Yet some row contains all strings and some row contains a mixed data type. The first step is to normalize them by remove all ending new lines. The `csv` module can take care of mixed data types just fine.

Comment: The issue here is that the nested list itself is being originally imported from the text file, to be edited, then put back in.

Comment: So the data can't be in the file originally

Comment: The data can be from a file or other sources. I put the data in the script as an example only.